# How to find the next link after an id with selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to return the links to all posts from a specific subreddit on my Reddit homepage. My intuition is to do this by looking for the next link after it finds an `href` = r/whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/

I would recommend using infinite scroll load.

Then after use this to grab all the links.

```
links = [x.get_attribute("href") for x in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@href and @data-click-id='body']")]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find all `a` tags with `href` attribute and after that, you can iterate through this list. 
 python implementation.

```py
driver = webdriver.WhateverDriver
links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@href]") # This will return all links
```